# Extracting Text From Asynchronus Request Using grequests

Tags: html, python-3.x, request, grequests

I am trying to extract the text part from the request that I made through grequest library but I am unable to figure out how can I do so.

If we use Requests Library I would do

```
r = requests.get('www.google.com')
htmls.append(r.text)
```

Now if I am using grequests I can only get a list of response code and not text.

```
rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
result = grequests.map(rs)
```

What I've tried
`result = grequests.map(rs.text)`

I get an error using above piece of code `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'text'`

My desired output is a list of html text where response code is 200 else the value should be None.
How can I achieve that?

Desired Output:

```
response_code = [<Response [200]>,<Response [404]>,<Response [200]>]
htmls = ['html1', None, 'html2']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like below

```py
rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
responses = grequests.map(rs)
text = list(map(lambda d : d.text if d else None, responses))

print(text)
```

What you are getting back is a response array after you call the map. And then you can process this data using native `map` function